# Request EC2 spot block with automated bidding using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Correct me if I'm wrong, but there seem to be some inconsistencies between creating sport block requests using EC2 console and AWS SDK (Boto3, namely). When requesting a spot block using AWS Management console, the only pricing option is "Use automated bidding".

[image]

However when doing the same [via Boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.request_spot_instances), `SpotPrice` parameter is marked as required with no indication that it might represent, say, a percentage of on-demand price.

Is there any option to use automated bidding programmatically without hard-coding on-demand prices in the requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console is merely trying to present a simplified process. I think it is simply setting `SpotPrice` to the on-demand price. That's a much cleaner interface than asking for a different price per selected Instance Type.

You always only pay the current Spot Price. Bidding is always automatic up to your Spot price, which represents the maximum you are willing to pay.

If you want to make an equivalent bid without hard-coding the On-Demand Price, you could use the [AWS PriceList API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/price-changes.html), which is really just some downloadable JSON/CSV files with pricing information. Pricing doesn't change very often, so you could cache that information and occasionally refresh it.

Comment: Yes, indeed you're right regarding Management console setting `SpotPrice` to the on-demand price. When I launched 2 identically configured spot instances (1 from console, 1 from SDK), both requests got the same `Max price` value.

Answer (score 0):

Because you choose **Reserved for duration**. Automatic bidding is the only way you can do this.

IMHO, you should consider your SPOT requirement before jump into **reserved for duration**.  If your application is **spot instance ready** , then you should specify a fleet of instance with your desire minimum price.  Because AWS Spot always has under utilised spare instance, in fact, this minimise the interruption without even the need of reservation.

Perhaps due to c4.* pricing and cause many people move from c3.* to c4.*, it seems c3.* pricing is all time low (e.g. us-east-1*  show a price below $0.02)